# Entity Framework 6 RC 1 issue - Could not load type 'System.Data.Entity.Config.SingletonDependencyResolver`1'

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Since upgrading to entity framework 6 rc 1 I've started receiving the following error when my dbcontext is initialising:

System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Data.Entity.Config.SingletonDependencyResolver`1' from assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Any ideas on a solution?  I can't find anything regarding this!

**EDIT**

I rolled back to beta 1, problem goes away.  Potential RC 1 bug...

Comment: Did you update any dependent packages as well?  In my case I updated entity framework, but not the sqlservercompact package.  (And as Pawel points out, some of the namespace were changed so it makes sense dependent packages broke.)

Answer (score 7):

if you have multiple projects referencing EntityFramwork and EntityFramework.SqlServer, Make sure you update each one of them. PM> Install-Package EntityFramework -Pre only update the default project.

Answer (score 0):

I also get an error after updating to RC1 when trying to add mapping classes to the model builder using:

modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

Error:

{"Method not found: 'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration`1<System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration> System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.StructuralTypeConfiguration`1.Property(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1<System.Func`2>)'."}

Rolling back to beta 1 also fixes my issue.  Seems like some types have been moved into different namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

`SingletonDependencyResolver` was moved to the `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution` namespace.

Here is the list of changes to public APIs between Beta1 and RC:

https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Design%20Meeting%20Notes%20July%2010%202013

Here is the changeset where the changes were made:

https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/eb3931b28fe64ae4531154fd7b0be3e2146eadd0